# MPEG 4 SDK for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, mpeg

can anyone recommend a MPEG4 library that will compile(or is compatible) with Intel or Visual C++?

EDIT: clarification

I was not aware of x264, and ffmpeg does not compile with VC++ (compiles with MingW). Basically I need a library that can be compiled on Windows (or the name of a vendor) that will allow me to extract frames and metadata embedded in the frames from the following MPEG: ID : 481 (0x1E1) Menu ID: 1 (0x1) Format: MPEG Video version: Version 2 profile: Main@High settings, BVOP: Yes settings, Matrix: Default Bit rate mode: Variable Standard: Component Resolution: 8 bits Colorimetry: 4:2:0 Scan type: Progressive List: 481 (0x1E1) (MPEG Video) / 497 (0x1F1) () KLVA_PID: 497

thank you,
T

Comment: I wanted to let everyone know that Intel IPP is available for free (Linux only) for personal, non-commercial use. http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/non-commercial-software-download/

Answer (score 3):

[Intel's IPP library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp/) have some encoders/decoders for various algorithms. It's not free though, but pretty affordable IMO. (You don't say if you need a non-cost solution or not.)

Comment: Thank you all. It seems IPP does the job.
regards,
T

Comment: I wanted to let everyone know that Intel IPP is available for free (Linux only) for personal, non-commercial use.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/non-commercial-software-download/

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention having tried either [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) or [x264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X264), I don't know if they compile with Intel or Visual C++, but they are the first libraries that spring to mind. And if you already tried these, you should mention what was unsatisfactory about them in your question,so that someone can perhaps suggest a library without the same disadvantage.

Comment: Thank you all. I was not aware of x264, and ffmpeg does not compile with VC++ (compiles with MingW).

Basically I need a library that can be compiled on Windows (or the name of a vendor) that will allow me to extract frames and metadata embedded in the frames from the following MPEG:
ID : 481 (0x1E1)
Menu ID: 1 (0x1)
Format: MPEG Video
version: Version 2
profile: Main@High
settings, BVOP: Yes
settings, Matrix: Default
Bit rate mode: Variable
Standard: Component
Resolution: 8 bits
Colorimetry: 4:2:0
Scan type: Progressive
List: 481 (0x1E1) (MPEG Video) / 497 (0x1F1) ()
KLVA_PID: 497

Comment: @user276319 You can also (I think, even though you are a newcomer) edit your question to provide the additional information there, that increases your chances of someone seeing it and providing a useful answer. I moved it there myself for this once (I can do it as an acknowledgement of the time I have already wasted here, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq for a table).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more complex than that - Mpeg4 covers a whole range of codecs, and it's not a simple area to work in.

Take a look at ffmpeg